# Algo to find optimum solution from a given dataset

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose i have a given data set.

```
 4 → a b c
 5 → l b d
 6 → e b c
42 → l b c
```

Here data items are in group such that their combined value is given in first column. To be more accurate, the items are clubbed in different ways.

The input to the algorithm should be the items.
Output should be the best possible combination through which we obtain all item set with minimum cost.

Example.
To get `b`, `c`, `l`, and `e` values, we need to take the row with a key of `5` and the row with the key of `6`. Returning the sum of `5` and `6`.

```
programm b c l e
    output: 11 = 5+6
```

Here, we must return `4+5 = 9`. Although the row with the key of `42` also matches the criteria, `9 < 42`.

```
programm l b c
    output: 9 = 4+5

programm e b c
    output: 6
```

Comment: Trying to understand what it is that you want. The item set `{a,b,c}` has got a value of `4`, `{l,b,d}` of `5`, etc. So, when the given input is `I = {b,c,l,e}` you're looking for a set `A` as a union of existing item sets so that `A` is a superset of `I` and `A` is the superset for which the value of the item sets it's been constructed from is minimal?

Comment: And the usual questions: What have you tried? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. The output should be such that cost of combination of sets should be mininum

Comment: Yes, i am trying. Idea is to use a dict for this purpose. 
which contain mapping for each element is input set with The given sets. Currently working on it. But help from a different point of view would be appreciated

Comment: @duck It would be preferable to put a high-level description of your attempt in the question (perhaps a fair bit more detailed than in your comment). Even if you're stuck trying to implement it (in which case you should describe the problem you're having).

Comment: Since the question got close-vote, I have edited it a bit in my attempt to highlight the OP's intent. Feel free to rollback my edit if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you can remove elements from the sets that are not part of the query set. Then, what remains is the weighted [Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_Cover) problem. It is NP-hard, thus difficult so solve optimally. Possibly the [greedy heuristic](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/course/2005/algo2/scribes/lecture2.pdf) is sufficient; if you really need an optimal solution, I'd try first to investigate whether your input instances have any properties that might be exploited, or otherwise use an ILP solver.

Comment: That for suggesting a solution, let me go through it

Comment: Thanks it helped, some inputs from the Setcover problem helped in solving the problem.